# Nginix directing to a host called "_"

Tags: linux, redirect, webserver, nginx

I have nginx all set up for my needs... it's a wildcard directory based hosting setup. My issue is that when a url is given without an extension or trailing slash, nginx redirects it to a host called "_" with the rest of the URL intact. What can I do to make nginx properly redirect the urls without trailing slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this directive in your config of the wildcard vhost:

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
```

Comment: Still does it sadly. It only does it for existing directories without the trailing slash. How come it just doesn't 404 without the slash? I'm a nginx noob ;D

Comment: My bad -> It actually did work, Safari just keep doing that stupid redirect thing.